# MySQL Java Use a JComboBox to set a second JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I am using MySQL server 5.6 to host a database that I am using to manage part number records. I have a Java client front end. My connections between the client and database are all good. In my panel to create parts, I have a JComboBox-typeComboBox that is populated by querying the database for all possible part types and displaying their type numbers in the drop down menu. Depending on the selection from that JComboBox the tdescripTextField and seqTextField are filled with the the appropriate information but I can not get the JComboBox-matComboBox to be populated by the appropriate results that are queried using the selected PartType number.

I have used a number of System.out.println(); to debug the part of the code where the issue is happening, and from what I can tell the String[] mats does contain the correct information, but it just wont assign it to the matComboBox. I notifced if I don't initialize matComboBox = new JComboBox(); right after the typeComboBox I get a compilation error saying that matComboBox is null.

Thanks in advance for any help.

p.s. all of my query methods return JSONArrays from the database.

```
class CreatePanel extends JPanel{
    //JButtons  
        private JButton saveButton;
        private JButton backButton;

    //JComboBox
        private JComboBox<?> typeComboBox;
        private JComboBox<?> matComboBox;

    //JTextField
        private JTextField tdescripTextField;
        private JTextField mdescripTextField;
        private JTextField descripTextField;
        private JTextField seqTextField;
        private JTextField bpartTextField;
        private JTextField cpartTextField;
        private JTextField spartTextField;

    //JLabel
        private JLabel lblSeq;
        private JLabel lblDescription;
        private JLabel lblMatterialDescription;
        private JLabel lblTypeDescription;
        private JLabel lblType;
        private JLabel lblMatterial;
        private JLabel lblBosalPartNumber;
        private JLabel lblCustomerPartNumber;
        private JLabel lblSupplierPartNumber;
        private JLabel lblCreateAPart;
        private JLabel Bosal;
        JPanel contentPane;

    //StringPanel   
        public CreatePanel(final JPanel create)
        {
    //TextFields

            tdescripTextField = new JTextField();
            tdescripTextField.setEditable(false);
            mdescripTextField = new JTextField();
            mdescripTextField.setEditable(false);
            descripTextField = new JTextField();
            seqTextField = new JTextField();
            seqTextField.setEditable(false);
            bpartTextField = new JTextField();
            bpartTextField.setEditable(false);
            cpartTextField = new JTextField();
            spartTextField = new JTextField();

    //ComboBoxes
            typeComboBox = new JComboBox<Object>();
            matComboBox = new JComboBox<Object>();
            JSONArray temp1 = new JSONArray();

            String[] types = null;

            try{
                temp1 = con.queryReturnAllTypes();
                types = new String[temp1.length()];

                for(int i = 0; i < temp1.length(); i++){
                    types[i] = temp1.getJSONObject(i).get("PartType").toString();
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){/*ignore*/}

            typeComboBox = new JComboBox<Object>(types);
            typeComboBox.setEditable(true);
            typeComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    int partType = Integer.valueOf((String) typeComboBox.getSelectedItem());
                    /*Debug*/System.out.println(partType);
                    JSONArray temp1 = new JSONArray();
                    JSONArray temp2 = new JSONArray();
                    String typeDescrip = null;
                    String seqNum = null;
                    String[] mats = null;

                    try{
                        temp1 = con.queryPartType(partType);
                        /*Debug*/System.out.println(temp1);
                        temp2 = con.queryMaterialPartType(partType);
                        /*Debug*/System.out.println(temp2);
                        mats = new String[temp2.length()];
                        /*Debug*/System.out.println(temp2.length());

                        typeDescrip = temp1.getJSONObject(0).get("TypeDescription").toString();
                        tdescripTextField.setText(typeDescrip);
                        seqNum = temp1.getJSONObject(0).get("SeqNumber").toString();
                        seqTextField.setText(seqNum);

                        for(int i = 0; i < temp2.length(); i++){
                            /*Debug*/System.out.println(i);
                            /*Debug*/System.out.println(temp2.getJSONObject(i).get("Material").toString());
                            mats[i] = temp2.getJSONObject(i).get("Material").toString();
                            /*Debug*/System.out.println(mats[i]);
                        }
                        for(int i = 0; i<mats.length; i++){
                            /*Debug*/System.out.println(mats[i]);

                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){/*ignore*/}    
                        for(int i = 0; i<mats.length; i++){
                            /*Debug*/System.out.println(mats[i]);

                        }
                    matComboBox = new JComboBox<Object>(mats);
                    matComboBox.setEditable(true);
                }

            });

    //Labels

            lblType = new JLabel("Type");
            lblMatterial = new JLabel("Material");
            lblTypeDescription = new JLabel("Type Description");
            lblMatterialDescription = new JLabel("Material Description");
            lblSeq = new JLabel("Seq");
            lblDescription = new JLabel("Description");
            lblBosalPartNumber = new JLabel("Bosal Part Number");
            lblCustomerPartNumber = new JLabel("Customer Part Number");
            lblSupplierPartNumber = new JLabel("Supplier Part Number");
            lblCreateAPart = new JLabel("Create a Part Number");

            ImageIcon bosal = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/bosal.jpg"));
            Bosal = new JLabel(bosal);
            setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    //Buttons

            ImageIcon save = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/save1.jpg"));
            saveButton = new JButton(save);
            saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource() == saveButton){
                        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                                frame,
                                "Are you sure you want to save part data?",
                                "Save:",
                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                    }}});
            add(saveButton);

            ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/back1.jpg"));
            backButton = new JButton(back);
            backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource() == backButton)
                    {

                        setVisible(false);
                        frame.setLocation(550,220);
                        frame.setSize(700, 580);
                        main.setVisible(true);

                    }}});
            add(backButton);

            setupPanel();

        };

        private void setupPanel() 

        {

    //Label Fonts

            lblType.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            lblType.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblMatterial.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            lblMatterial.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblTypeDescription.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            lblTypeDescription.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblMatterialDescription.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            lblMatterialDescription.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblDescription.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            lblDescription.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblSeq.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            lblSeq.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblSupplierPartNumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            lblSupplierPartNumber.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblCreateAPart.setFont(new Font("EucrosiaUPC", Font.BOLD, 64));
            lblCreateAPart.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblCustomerPartNumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            lblCustomerPartNumber.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblBosalPartNumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            lblBosalPartNumber.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    //Group Layout  

            GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(this);
            groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(24)
                                .addComponent(Bosal, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 199, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(6)
                                .addComponent(lblCreateAPart, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 434, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(50)
                                .addComponent(lblType)
                                .addGap(121)
                                .addComponent(lblTypeDescription)
                                .addGap(163)
                                .addComponent(lblBosalPartNumber))
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(50)
                                .addComponent(typeComboBox, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(76)
                                .addComponent(tdescripTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 211, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(67)
                                .addComponent(bpartTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(50)
                                .addComponent(lblMatterial)
                                .addGap(101)
                                .addComponent(lblMatterialDescription)
                                .addGap(143)
                                .addComponent(lblCustomerPartNumber))
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(50)
                                .addComponent(matComboBox, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(76)
                                .addComponent(mdescripTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 211, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(67)
                                .addComponent(cpartTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(50)
                                .addComponent(lblSeq)
                                .addGap(129)
                                .addComponent(lblDescription)
                                .addGap(201)
                                .addComponent(lblSupplierPartNumber))
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(331)
                                .addComponent(backButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 157, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(41)
                                .addComponent(saveButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(50)
                                .addComponent(seqTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(97)
                                .addComponent(descripTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 211, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(67)
                                .addComponent(spartTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(32)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(Bosal, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(lblCreateAPart, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(6)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(lblType)
                            .addComponent(lblTypeDescription)
                            .addComponent(lblBosalPartNumber))
                        .addGap(6)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(typeComboBox, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(3)
                                .addComponent(tdescripTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(3)
                                .addComponent(bpartTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(6)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(lblMatterial)
                            .addComponent(lblMatterialDescription)
                            .addComponent(lblCustomerPartNumber))
                        .addGap(6)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(matComboBox, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(mdescripTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(cpartTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(9)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(lblSeq)
                            .addComponent(lblDescription)
                            .addComponent(lblSupplierPartNumber))
                        .addGap(6)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(seqTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(descripTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(spartTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(37)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(saveButton, 0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(backButton, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addContainerGap(135, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            setLayout(groupLayout); 
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a combo box, which is already displayed in the panel. What you want is to popule this already existing combo box.

But your code does

```
matComboBox = new JComboBox<Object>(mats);
```

So it creates another JComboBox, populated with the `mats` that you retrieved. That won't popukate your existing, displayed combo box. What you need to do is to change the data inside the combo box:

```
matComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(mats));
```